# C# xml: How to save nested rows

Tags: c#, xml, format, nested, save

I'm new to xml and I'm trying to save something in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <brickTable>
    <value>23039</value>
    <Tile>Brick</Tile>
    <X>18400</X>
    <Y>64</Y>
    <items>
          <itemType>Type1</itemType> 
    </items>
    <items>
           <itemType>Type5</itemType>
    </items>
  </brickTable>
</NewDataSet>
```

I would like the  to be part of the bricktable as shown but I can't figure out how to do it. I currently have the format above but without any of the  parts.

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
            System.Data.DataSet ds;
            ds = new DataSet();

            System.Data.DataTable tile_table;
            tile_table = new DataTable("tiles");

            //add an auto increment column
            DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn();
            column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            column1.ColumnName = "value";
            column1.AutoIncrement = true;
            tile_table.Columns.Add(column1);

            //add index key
            DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
            keys[0] = column1;
            tile_table.PrimaryKey = keys;

            //tilemap data columns
            DataColumn TileType = new DataColumn();
            TileType.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            TileType.ColumnName = "Tile";
            tile_table.Columns.Add(TileType);

            DataColumn X = new DataColumn();
            X.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            X.ColumnName = "X";
            tile_table.Columns.Add(X);

            DataColumn Y = new DataColumn();
            Y.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            Y.ColumnName = "Y";
            tile_table.Columns.Add(Y);

            DataRow row = tile_table.NewRow();
            row["value"] = count;
            row["Tile"] = tileListRear[index].tileType.ToString();
            row["X"] = tileListRear[index].X;
            row["Y"] = tileListRear[index].Y;
            row["Layer"] = NewMapEditor.Layer.Rear.ToString();
            tile_table.Rows.Add(row);

            //save xml file
            ds.Tables.Add(infoTable);
            ds.Tables.Add(tile_table);
            ds.WriteXml(g_filename);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant get an XML file like that from using 'DataSet.WriteXML'.

You could implement your own custom WriteXML function that derives from the 'ISerializeable' interface. This is probably a good idea if you are building a database or going to want a lot of control over how your data is serialized. Here is an [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).

How bad do you really need a DataTable? Are you going to be using SQL? Do you need relations?

If your goal is, as you say, to generate an XML file that exactly matches your example, you might want to start by storing your data in a class:

```
public class BrickTable
{
    public int      Value   { get; set; }
    public string   Title   { get; set; }
    public int      X       { get; set; }
    public int      Y       { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("ItemType")]
    public List<string> Items   { get; set; }

    public BrickTable()
    {
    }
}
```

Note: Items can be a list of string, a list of Type, or your own custom class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public string   Type    { get; set; }
    public int      Value   { get; set; }   
    public Item()
    {
    }
}
```

And its serializing function:

```
public void SerializeObject(string filename,object obj)
{
    using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter,obj);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
void Test() 
{
    BrickTable bTable = new BrickTable();

    bTable.Title    = "";
    bTable.Value    = 23039;
    bTable.X            = 18400;
    bTable.Y            = 64;


    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    items.Add("Item1");
    items.Add("Item5");

    bTable.Items = items;

    SerializeObject("BrickSet.xml",bTable);
}
```

Finally, you can make a function that takes a data row and returns a filled out a BrickTable class, or you can convert a class into a DataTable using reflection, [as shown here](http://csharpcodewhisperer.blogspot.com/2013/07/class-to-datatable.html).

So the question is, how badly do you need your XML to be formatted in that way? Does it also need to be in the form of a DataTable, also?